# SSAS: Can I define a Cube In BIDS, but create/process the partitions in SSMS/SSIS?

Tags: ssas

I am new to SSAS, and exploring Partitioning. My data source is very large (web logs):a few hundred million records.

I would like to define my cube IN BIDS, and create a SSIS Package to create partitions. For now, I am Generating The MDX to Create & process the partitions, and Executing them in SSMS.

I find that this is faster and less error prone them manually creating the partitions using the BIDS UI.

I am trying to understand the expected workflow: because every time I go back to BIDS, and make changes to measures  & process the cube the partitions I created in SSMS are deleted and the old partitions I created in BIDS are re-published.

What I would like to be able to do is Refresh my partitions from the server to BIDS. Is This possible? If not, what type of workflow is expected in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: You should really create the partitions in BIDS.  When you deploy your cube or a measure, you are deploying everything including partitions (except maybe security if you are using the deployment tool). Technically, you could open a cube from the server (this is the live cube, so be careful), save the project over your old project and work from there, but that is not a good workflow.  At best you could export the script to deploy rather than just deploy from BIDS and then edit the XMLA before running it in SSMS, but again this is not optimal.

Comment: If you are frequently updating your partitions for a particular measure, you could look into [dynamic partitioning](http://sql-bi-dev.blogspot.com/2010/12/dynamic-cube-partitioning-in-ssas-2008.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partitions are part of the cube structure, and if you change these outside of BIDS, then you change the structure of the deployed Analysis Services database. BIDS keeps the definition of the structure locally as a set of XML files, the partition definitions are contained in a file with the extension `.partitions`. If you deploy an Analysis Services project from BIDS, it updates the deployed Analysis Services database to match the structure of the local XML files, thus overwriting whatever you changed outside of BIDS.

You can get a deployed database back to an Analysis Services project as follows: Open BIDS, click File/New/Project, and then select "Import Analysis Services Database" from the "Business Intelligence Projects" project type, and select the directory where you want to save the project files locally in the bottom part of the dialog. As soon as you click OK, a wizard opens that allows you to select the server and Analysis Services database to get the definition from, and when you click Next, starts writing it to the directory that you selected.

Comment: Thank you for the details. This makes the role of BIDS clearer. I am surprized that data and cube definition are not decoupled... It must be my programming background that makes this seem odd. There must be a good reason for this. Glad to know I am not missing a BIDS feature that would do this for me.

BTW, I ended up editing the .Partitions file, but not worth it. there are a good amount of UI-related GUIDS,making it more of a hassle than using the ui

Comment: The cube/structure definition is decoupled in AS from the data contents. Just the structure of the partitions is part of the structure, and can be changed in more tools than just BIDS. And I described a way how to get that structure information back to BIDS. If you look at relational databases, the situation is more like you describe it: there normally is no such thing as a common structure definition which is contained in a set of XML files. Everybody having the permission can create/change/drop tables/views.

Answer (score 0):

Partitions are a part of your cube structure. You should create the partitions in BIDS and then process them based on your requirement using SSIS or SSMS.