# Change the storage mode of partition

Tags: ssas

Is there a way to change the storage mode of the partitions. If yes, how to do it through BIDS and SSMS?I did try to change it through SSMS by right clicking the partition and selected proactive caching, but I did not see any change in BIDS. Also, currently the partition is stored in MOLAP mode, and trying to save it in ROLAP mode.

Comment: If you change anything on a deployed cube in SSMS, this will **not** be reflected in BIDS. See my answer to this question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869385/ssas-can-i-define-a-cube-in-bids-but-create-process-the-partitions-in-ssms-ssi/21874935#21874935

Comment: @FrankPl: You Rock...Thanks a ton for the explanation...Can you please suggest me any good book on SSAS?